# MySQL Can't RENAME TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, rename

In MySQL,

I want to change my table's name.

For example:

```
RENAME TABLE old_table to old;
```

Than I can meet syntax error message.

But:

```
RENAME TABLE old_table to old_;
```

It is success.

I don't want to use `_(underscore)`.

Comment: what sort of error message you gotten?

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get, if you expect reasonable answers.

Comment: Do you already have an 'old' table? Please post your error message.

Comment: Post your error message. Even when I set `sql_mode` to `ansi,strict_all_tables` I don't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

ALTER TABLE oldTableName
rename to newTableName